# What type of diagram should I use?

Tags: relations, diagramming

I'm designing a new workflow system in my company. Currently it's a module developed in an old framework that draws a entity relationships diagram, such as this:

[image: Diagram currently in a production environment]

Thing is, we need to look into another way of displaying this information in another way, as **there are too many many-to-many relationships**, consequently drawing too many arrows to actually have a clear understanding of what's going on.

I'm looking into other possibilities, but I can't seem to find a good alternative. **The key needs are**:

- Many-to-many relationships
- Relationships may advance from the first column to the second, connect a first-column entity to another first-column entity, come back from third to second columns...
- Clear visualisation of the relationships (arrows)

Any thoughts of where I should look into? Thanks!

Comment: Many-to-many relationships sound like a potential case for using a matrix. You might find something that suits in the FT Visual Vocabulary page: https://ft-interactive.github.io/visual-vocabulary/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that having Straight edged relation lines would be more clear.
[image]

You could signalize direction, apart from arrows, also with color (LTR easy Green, RTL easy red, same column relations dotted line).

At your case I think extracting one entity relation functionality would provide even clearer insight. Please see below similiar functionality from GA Interface where second entity in first column is extracted.

[image]

Comment: Thanks xul :) I'm looking into possible ways of isolating a focused element (i.e. clicking on it) so the user could see the relationship of said element solely. The arrow arranging sounds right, my only concern is with column 1 to column 3 (or 3 to 1) elements, I don't want arrows crossing the entire diagram. Maybe with U-shaped arrows starting from the opposite direction?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Google Analytics Behavior Flow

It does a few things that could be helpful

- Many to many relationships
- Highlighting relationships from and to a selected page
- Size of elements is based on importance (traffic in this case)
- Less important elements will be hidden in a "see more" link (not in this image)

[image: google analytics behavior flow]

Comment: Thanks! My main concern is that with this flow I don't know how I should represent a returning (same column or backwards) relationship, if it's possible at all. If I'm understanding correctly this diagram represents a sort of a timelined/step-based/sequenced diagram. The one I need is not necessarily sequential. I like the grouping of elements, though, will look into it to see if this can fit in our interests.